# I am trying to do union of three lists of type T in C# , but when any of them is null it throws null reference exception

Tags: c#, union

Here is my code snippet:

```
var joinedList = List1.List.Where(x => x != null)
.Union(List2.List.Where(x=> x!= null).Union(List3.List.Where(x => x!= null))).ToList();
```

Comment: What did you expect? Calling `Where()` on a reference that is `null` will throw. So test for `null` before calling `Where()`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var joinedList = new List<T>();
if (List1.List != null) joinedList = joinedList.Union(List1.List.Where(x=>x!=null);
if (List2.List != null) joinedList = joinedList.Union(List2.List.Where(x=>x!=null);
if (List3.List != null) joinedList = joinedList.Union(List3.List.Where(x=>x!=null);
```

Comment: It should be `var joinedList = Enumerable.Empty<T>()`.  Your current code won't compile since .Union will return an `IEnumerable<T>` not a `List<T>`

Comment: @Paul , Thanks for your response , I used the same approach and was able to achieve the desired outcome.